# Can I use word2vec vectors as input features to NMF or LDA?

Tags: natural-language, topic-models, word2vec, latent-dirichlet-alloc, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I'm trying to do some topic modelling on my corpus and I want to use Word2Vec vectors as an input to my NMF and LDA models. How do I do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.

LDA requires the topic-word distribution $p(w|z)$ to be multinomial, which is designed for the bag-of-words representation. If $w$ is word2vec vector, $p(w|z)$ might just be an arbitrary distribution on high dimensional space, which is more difficult to model.

NMF is essentially matrix decomposition for document-term matrices $X\approx WH$, where $W$, $H$ and $X$ must have no negative elements. AFAIK popular word2vec vectors have negative values so it's not suitable either.

Comment: @charmander you're welcome :)